# Difference between EASA and FAA regulations for airliners?

Tags: airliner, faa, regulations, easa

The design of large transport aircraft is governed by EASA's CS-25 regulation and the FAA's FAR Part 25 regulation.

It seems however that these regulations are nearly identical. It is obvious that a lot of collaboration took place between the two authorities in the creation of these standards.

Are there any ***major*** differences between these standards?

Comment: Unless there are just too many large differences, I don't think this question is too broad.

Comment: I know the regulations are massive documents and with a lot of sections and I'm sure there are a few small differences but am really interested, as the question states, in major differences.

Comment: @Jonny I'd make your intention to ask for the major differences only easier to recognize in the question. Formatting helps a lot here ;)

Comment: There are literally thousands of differences between them, including many major ones. This question is indeed too broad.

Comment: Unless this is converted to a community wiki, the question is too broad.

Comment: My motivation for the question was driven by the study of the Sections to do with emergency egress (See sections 25.803,807,809,810,811,812,813,815,817,819 and 25.820) These sections all have the exact same names and numbers in both regulations. I see emergency egress as a major part of the regulations and in this regard the regs are in nearly exact alignment. I understand that there will be many many minor differences but I truly don't believe that, from the perspective of aircraft design, there are so many major differences. After all, the aircraft are operated on a global stage and

Comment: surely need to adhere to the regulations of the countries in which they are serviced and operated.